# Can I manually specify Sound Output device in the Mac (like in Windows/Linux)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

In the Mac, is there a way to choose whether I want sound output through my internal speakers or the headphones (i.e. the audio port), irrespective of whether there are headphones plugged in or not.

I can do this in Windows and Linux and I really need to be able to do this on the Mac as well, for a certain reason.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think the general consensus on this appears to be 'no' ... but have you tried something like Soundflower or Jack Audio, which allow non-standard routings. I can't test for headphones here, as I'm on a Mac Pro, but it might be worth 5 mins of your time to try it - http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/ or http://jackaudio.org